# Installing P-trap on vanity going from 1 1/4 to 2 inch drain pipe

Tags: plumbing, vanity

I installed a new vanity recently as I am wrapping up a bathroom remodel but when I went to install the p-trap I realized that the p-trap is 1 1/4 inches and the drain pipe at the wall is 2 inches. I looked online for more info and to see what kind of adapters I may need but I couldn't seem to find anything. Are there adapters I can get for such a large diameter change? Are there online resources that I just didn't find? Thanks!

Comment: A common scenario is the reducer Ed posted, then a short run of pipe, then a threaded end fitting, all cemented in place. Everything upstream of that uses compression fittings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2" to 1-1/4" reducer [like this should work](http://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/2-x-1-1-4-sch-40-pvc-reducer-coupling-soc-429-250.html?gclid=CMOFw83IjM8CFQdqfgodApcCwg). This was the first one I found but they are out there. Home stores should stock them also.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it, you could put a 2x1 1/2 bushing on there and a small piece of 1 1/2 to your adapter.